# How to monitor a directory with time and file using inotifywait?

Tags: linux, bash, inotifywait

I need to listen a directory, I can listen if a file is created in this directory and it works

```
inotifywait -m -r -e moved_to -e create "$DIR" --format "%f" | while read f 
do
        if [[ $f = *.csv ]] ; then
                do something
        fi

done
```

But, if this file not created, I need to send emails at 12:00 and 19:00 (at 19:00) I need to kill the process.

So, how can I monitor file and system time using inotifywait? I tried using double conditions in while, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use [incrontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) with [incrond(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond). Of course you should install it and combine with [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

My opinion is that [scripting languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) like [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Python](http://python.org/), [Lua](https://lua.org/) are better suited for such tasks. You'll find extensions to them related to  [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

> I need to send emails at 12:00 and 19:00 (at 19:00)

That is more a job for [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

Comment: Can I use those guys if nothing happens?

How my script should work? 

Thank you for your help